# Rails - Link two field from one table to another one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship

i'm trying to make a relationship between two table, but i dont know the right way to do it.

I have two table

First one:

```
User     (table)
username (field)
email    (field)
password (field)
```

Second table:

```
Friend     (table)
friend_one (field)
friend_two (field)
```

I want to make a relationship like this:

```
User has_many "friend_one"
User has_many "friend_two"
-----
"friend_one" belongs_to User
"friend_two" belongs_to User
```

I have google it and i did not find any exemple that fit what i try to do. Anyone know how i can create this kind of relationship in Rails?

Thx and have a nice day all.

Comment: Explain exactly what you want to achieve and why this approach ?

Comment: what is difference between friend_one and friend_two?

Comment: Its to make a friendship relationship, friend_one will have an User id, and friend_two another User id. Exemple, if friend_one have User id 1, and friend_two have User id 2, that make the friend relationship. No duplicate needed with friend_one User id 2, friend_two User id 1.